# How to zoom InteractiveView to clicked point?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

Is there any way to zoom InteractiveView using TransformationController to clicked point? I can do it only from initial position(Matrix4.identity), but is there a way to do it from any position?